# Chocolate mousse without eggs

Tags: eggs, dessert, chocolate, mousse, molecular-gastronomy

I've a friend who is allergic to egg protein, and my wife inadvertently raved about my chocolate mousse to her, causing some food borne awkwardness that I'd like to erase with an eggless mousse.

I've done some experimenting though, and I'm not happy with the results. Can anyone think of a substitution that would hold air and provide the light mousse-y texture, but not be an egg? Can't be corn-based either, due to an additional corn allergy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been pleased with [this](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/good-eats/chocolate-mousse-recipe/index.html) Good Eats recipe in the past, which uses whipped cream plus gelatin; have you tried this yet?

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest. Whipped cream for lightness, gelatine for stability.

Answer (score 11):

Try [Hervé This's chocolate Chantilly](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2001/nov/10/foodanddrink.recipes).  Water plus chocolate.  Quite stunning.

Comment: It is amazing and quick to make. The portions need to be a bit smaller, as it's rich.  Sometimes I dilute This' Chantilly with whipped cream.

Comment: Ended up going with the "Good Eats" version that Dennis posted, but I topped it with some of your suggested Chantilly. First class.

Answer (score 3):

We have been making mousse with [aquafaba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquafaba) (the liquid drained off a can of chickpeas). It's whisked by the food processor into a thick foam and then the chocolate is folded in.  Quite popular approach in vegan circles.

Answer (score 2):

An egg is such an amazing little thing that it doesn't really have any direct substitutes. To get the lightest eggless mouse possible you'll have to stick to heavy cream, sugar, and chocolate.

Gently melt 3.5 oz. of dark chocolate over low heat. While that melts, whip together 5 oz. of heavy cream and 1 oz. of sugar until it's foamy. When the chocolate is ready, gently fold it into the whipped cream. Pour it into your serving dishes (serves 4-6) and refrigerate for at least an hour until cool.

This won't be as rich or as light as mousse made with eggs, but it's still good!

Answer (score 0):

Silken tofu mousse recipes couldn't be easier. Yes, can get it quite light. Maybe not as aerated as with egg or gelatin but without the off flavors of either

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound rather unorthodox, but whipping chilled instant chocolate pudding will make a nice mousse substitute. I can't call it mousse really, but you honestly can't tell the difference unless you are taste testing side by side with one made from fresh shaved chocolate. Obviously the real mousse will be much richer when tasted side by side, but this trick works as a cheap, quick and very easy substitute.