# Would baking a cake for 2 hours at 350 degrees F be safe to eat if it's still moist?

Tags: baking, food-safety, eggs

I'm trying to modify a recipe for a cake which calls for 3 cups of shredded butter nut squash. I thought I could replace this with roughly the same amount of pureed pumpkin (like what you would get in a jar).

However, the cake is still moist inside, after more than doubling the baking time it originally called for.

I don't mind that the consistency is too wet, I'm only concerned about cooking the eggs enough. Unfortunately, I don't have a thermometer to test the internal temperature. Is it safe to assume that at 350 degrees F, with the cake baking for more than 2 hours, that it reached the [internal temperature of 138 degrees](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/chocolate-mousse-with-cooked-eggs/6163#6163)?

The cake is about 1.5 inches in height. I baked it for 1:10 minutes, then an extra 1 hour with tin foil on top (to prevent the top from burning). The top and bottom of the cake are not moist at all.

Comment: I would advise that you check your oven temperature with a good oven thermometer.

Comment: While not answering the question directly - a comment on the substitution.  You probably had far too much pumpkin.  Shredded anything will have quite a bit of air in it.  So I suggest if you try again you use just two cups or even less of the pureed as a "more equivalent" substitute.

Comment: Yet another substitution note. The canned/jarred pumpkin is cooked and pureed, which is much more condensed than fresh shredded squash or pumpkin. I think a good starting point for a substitution is about 1 cup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't see any possible way it didn't reach 138F inside after that length of time! I think you just had way too much liquid.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are very young, very old, or immunocompromised in some way (chemotherapy, leukemia, HIV, etc), slightly undercooked eggs are fine.